# Drawing a 3D circular arrow around a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab-figure, tikz, arrows

How do I create a   circular arrow (in3D) in Matlab? As shown in the figure below, I have a vector *v* and want to draw a circular arrow around the vector to show the direction of Torque.

[image]

Comment: Not a [tikz] question?